how to launch an app as a different user in winappdriver?
I have been working on a problem, where I want to login to windows and launch an application as a different user as part of the testing scheme.
ie.

login as user 1
set and alarm as user 1
login as user 2
view alarms, and clear them if they exist
log back in as user 1
check if alarm exists or if it was deleted by user 2.
end

Is is better to launch the application as a different user at launch, or is it better to use the windows login, to login to the system as a different user and run the app.
I have this sample app, that runs the "Windows Alarms", which I found on the internet. Can I sepecify a user account with the wdio config file ?
wdio.conf.js
require('ts-node').register({ transpileOnly: true });

exports.config = {
    runner: "local",

    specs: ["src/test/specs/*.ts"],
  
    maxInstances: 1,
  
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: [
      {
        //app: "Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App",
          app: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe",
        "ms:experimental-webdriver": true,
        browserName: "",
      },
    ],
    logLevel: "trace",
    services: ["winappdriver"],
    framework: "jasmine",
    outputDir: ".\\reports",
    reporters: ["dot", ["junit", { outputDir: ".\\reports" }]],
  
    before() {
      //implicit wait for 5 seconds
      browser.setTimeout({ implicit: 5000 });
    },
  
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
      expectationResultHandler: function (passed, assertion) {
        /**
         * only take screenshot if assertion failed
         */
        if (passed) {
          return;
        }
  
        browser.getPageSource();
        browser.saveScreenshot(
          `.\\reports\\assertionError_${assertion.error.message}.png`
        );
      },
    }
}


and then have a test that preforms the login to windows before doing the actual testing in the Alarm app.
/**
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */

import LoginPage from "../pageobjects/WindowsLoginPage";
import HomePage from "../pageobjects/HomePage";
import AlarmsPage from "../pageobjects/AlarmsPage";
import TimerPage from "../pageobjects/TimerPage";
import AddTimerPage from "../pageobjects/AddTimerPage";
import SettingsPage from "../pageobjects/SettingsPage";

describe("Samples", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {});

  it("Windows login", () => {
    LoginPage.gotoLogin();



  });

  it("Goto AddTimer Page", () => {
    HomePage.gotoTimerPage();
    TimerPage.waitForPageLoaded();

    TimerPage.gotoAddTimerPage();
    AddTimerPage.waitForPageLoaded();

    AddTimerPage.cancelAndGotoHomePage();
  });

Has anyone done this sort of trickery before?
I saw an example of using the windows on-screen keyword to navigate the windows login, I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this...
Thanks in advance!
X
